# Undelete question with TOO MANY CAPITALS

Tags: discussion

I reformatted the answer that was in all caps for this question:

https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/9777/92

I think it's a decent answer, now that it's readable, and I'd like to ask for it to be undeleted.

I'd also suggest, in cases like this, where the answer is clearly in good faith, that we add a comment letting the poster know why they were deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that, properly formatted it's a pretty decent answer. We should be encouraging people to write detailed answers like this one, even if they need some help on things like spelling, grammar, and formatting. I have undeleted it.

Comment: Of course we should help people with spelling, grammar, and formatting, but deliberately writing everything in capitals and letting the community fix it, is just antisocial.

Comment: I agree, but it seems like we could allow absolute newbies a little slack.